# magento 2 cart price rule

Tags: magento2

I need to create cart price rule Buy x get Y with 50% discount ,Conditions are Buy 1 bag get 1  t-shirt 50 % offer

**Scenarios**
1), Bag 2 or equals or greater than t-shirt 1 -rule apply
2) ,Bag 1 t-shirt 1 equals or greater than    - rule apply
3) ,Bag 1 t-shirt 1                           - rule apply

How create this in custom can anyone help me or give ideas  to create this?